# Script won't read the service line by line from txt file, it combline them instead

Tags: powershell, service, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

This is the script I have, I'm trying to have it read a list of services from the text but it instead combines them together. For example,  I have two services(RTCRGS and TabletInputService), it will read it as
 " RTCRGS TabletInputService " instead of one service at a time.

```
$Serverstxt = "C:\Scripts\Services\Server.txt"
$Servicestxt = "C:\Scripts\Services\Services.txt"

$ServiceList = get-content "$Servicestxt"
$ServerList = get-content "$Serverstxt"


#Initialize variables:
[string]$WaitForIt = ""
[string]$Verb = ""
[string]$Result = "FAILED"


#
foreach($Server in $ServerList){
    foreach($Service in $ServiceList){

    $svc = (get-service -computername $Server -name $Service)
    Write-host "$Service on $Sever is $($svc.status)"
    Switch ($svc.status) {
    'Stopped' {
        Write-host "Starting $Service..."
        $Verb = "start"
        $WaitForIt = 'Running'
        $svc.Start()}
    'Running' {
        Write-host "Stopping $Service..."
        $Verb = "stop"
        $WaitForIt = 'Stopped'
        $svc.Stop()}
    Default {
        Write-host "$Service is $($svc.status).  Taking no action."}
}
if ($WaitForIt -ne "") {
    Try {  
# For some reason, we cannot use -ErrorAction after the next statement:
        $svc.WaitForStatus($WaitForIt,'00:02:00')
    } Catch {
        Write-host "After waiting for 2 minutes, $Service failed to $Verb."
    }


    $svc = (get-service -computername $Server -name $Service)
    if ($svc.status -eq $WaitForIt) {$Result = 'SUCCESS'}
    Write-host "$Result`: $Service on $Server is $($svc.status)"
}
```

Comment: I think i did something wrong with the "For each" command.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` is correct, but you are using the entire list, instead of each element throughout your loop.

`$SvrNames` and `$SvcNames` are the contents of the files.

`$SvrName` and `$SvcName` are the current loop variables.

So you'd use
`$svc = (get-service -computername $SvrName -name $SvcName)`
and so on, inside the loop.

To make things a bit clearer, rename the variables

```
$Serverstxt = "C:\Scripts\Services\Server.txt"
$Servicestxt = "C:\Scripts\Services\Services.txt"

$ServiceList = get-content "$Servicestxt"
$ServerList = get-content "$Serverstxt"

foreach($Server in $ServerList){
    foreach($Service in $ServiceList){
    # . . . 
    $svc = (get-service -computername $Server -name $Service)
    # . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated it but still having the same problem when I have multiple services... It will just stick together..

Comment: You removed the loop, but you are still looking at the entire list.  Answer updated, hope it makes things clearer.